# HTML - Store checkbox value locally and retrieve

Tags: javascript, database, html, checkbox

I am developing a HTML web application. I have five checkboxes and I have to store the checked values locally when I click SAVE sutton. I have to retrieve the checked data from the local storage and display it when I click SHOW button. I have no idea how to do this. Help me to complete this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: dont forget to upvote and accept answer if it works for you ...........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/sQuEy/4/

Remember that to set a checkbox value in javascript you need to use a boolean value, but web storage saves all values as strings. So:

```
checkboxes[i].checked = localStorage.getItem(checkboxes[i].value) === 'true' ? true:false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code

Incorporating three simple functions from [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html), you can do this:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}

createCookie("checkboxes", $("input:checkbox").serialize(), 30);
alert(readCookie("checkboxes"));
```